# Need to make ' ', work

Tags: python

```
file = open("SampleList.txt", "r")
x = file.readlines()
y = []
for i in range (len(x)):
    print x[i].split()
```

This is the code I have and this is the output

```
['100000,Weasely', ',Bill', ',9,1', 'Discipline,0']
['120001,Weasely', ',Fred', ',10,1', 'Discipline,0']
['120002,Weasley', ',George', ',6,1', 'Tardies,0']
['130003,Weasley', ',Ronald', ',10,OK,0']
['130004,Longbottom', ',Neville', ',5,1', 'Absence,0']
['130005,Potter', ',Harry', ',5,OK,0']
['130006,MAlfoy', ',Draco', ',5,1', 'Owes', 'more', 'than', '$5,$150.00']    
['100118,The', 'House', 'Elf', ',Dobbey', ',7,OK,0']
['100011,LaStrange', ',Belatrix', ',8,1', 'Discipline,0']
['100170,Dumbledore', ',Albus', ',7,1', 'Administration,0']
>>>
```

what I need is ['the number', 'last name', 'first name', and so on]

Comment: why not `x[i].split(',')`

Comment: You're currently splitting on whitespace. If that's not what you want, *split on something else*. Also, note the `csv` library for exactly this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

You could transform your file to a .csv format and say

```
import csv

with open('SampleList.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

maybe?